# Unexpected SELECT permissions

Tags: sql-server, schema, select, permissions

My user WebApp seems to have SELECT permissions on every table in every schema and I can't figure out why.

- WebApp is only in the Public role.
- Public doesn't own any schema.
- Explicit permissions haven't been set on the tables in question
- Effective permissions, as reported by SSMS, show it has SELECT permission

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. A bad script granted database-wide SELECT permissions to the user. Found it using this script:

```
WITH    perms_cte as
(
        select USER_NAME(p.grantee_principal_id) AS principal_name,
                dp.principal_id,
                dp.type_desc AS principal_type_desc,
                p.class_desc,
                OBJECT_NAME(p.major_id) AS object_name,
                p.permission_name,
                p.state_desc AS permission_state_desc 
        from    sys.database_permissions p
        inner   JOIN sys.database_principals dp
        on     p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
)
--users
SELECT p.principal_name,  p.principal_type_desc, p.class_desc, p.[object_name], p.permission_name, p.permission_state_desc, cast(NULL as sysname) as role_name
FROM    perms_cte p
WHERE   principal_type_desc <> 'DATABASE_ROLE'
UNION
--role members
SELECT rm.member_principal_name, rm.principal_type_desc, p.class_desc, p.object_name, p.permission_name, p.permission_state_desc,rm.role_name
FROM    perms_cte p
right outer JOIN (
    select role_principal_id, dp.type_desc as principal_type_desc, member_principal_id,user_name(member_principal_id) as member_principal_name,user_name(role_principal_id) as role_name--,*
    from    sys.database_role_members rm
    INNER   JOIN sys.database_principals dp
    ON     rm.member_principal_id = dp.principal_id
) rm
ON     rm.role_principal_id = p.principal_id
order by 1
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20141128165740/http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2007/02/09/SQL-Server-2005_3A00_-View-all-permissions--_2800_2_2900_.aspx